# Entry widget 'get' call does not update after an 'Insert' has been used

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a series of Entry widget text boxes (Name, Number, Email etc) That I use to collect or display contact information. If I populate these and 'add' them to my sqlite, this works correctly. If however I select an existing contact and populate these boxes with existing data, then modify an entry and try to add this modified entry to the sqlite database the Entry.get(x) command only ever pulls the data that was in the text box before I populated it from an existing entry.

For example, I create a new contact 'Bob' this saves OK. I change 'Bob' to 'Frank' this also saves.
I then populate the fields from an existing entry 'Michael', no matter what I now do, I only ever retrieve 'Frank' as the entry in this box. The insert seems to lock the entry.

```
def CurSelet(event=None):
    i_contact = populate(int((listbox1.curselection()[0])))

def populate(index):
    site_id = (Entry.get(x))
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM sites WHERE site_id=?', (site_id,))
    site_info = c.fetchall()
    pop_name(site_info,index)
    pop_num(site_info,index)
    pop_email(site_info,index)
    pop_mob(site_info,index)
    conn.close()

def pop_name(site_info,index):
    cne = Entry(root)
    cne.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=2)
    cne.focus()
    cne.delete(0, tk.END)
    cne.insert(0, (site_info[index])[1])


def pop_num(site_info,index):
    cnbre = Entry(root)
    cnbre.grid(row=2, column=8, columnspan=2)
    cnbre.focus()
    cnbre.delete(0, tk.END)
    cnbre.insert(0, (site_info[index])[2])

def pop_email(site_info,index):
    cee = Entry(root)
    cee.grid(row=3, column=8, columnspan=2)
    cee.focus()
    cee.delete(0, tk.END)
    cee.insert(0, (site_info[index])[3])

def pop_mob(site_info,index):
    cme = Entry(root)
    cme.grid(row=4, column=8, columnspan=2)
    cme.focus()
    cme.delete(0, tk.END)
    cme.insert(0, (site_info[index])[4])

def add():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM sites')
    #print c.fetchall()    
    site_id = (Entry.get(x))
    contact_name = (Entry.get(cne))
    print(contact_name)
    contact_number = (Entry.get(cnbre))
    contact_email = (Entry.get(cee))
    contact_mobile = (Entry.get(cme))
    contact_alt = (Entry.get(cae))
    c.execute("insert into sites values (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(site_id, contact_name, contact_number, contact_email, contact_mobile, contact_alt))
    #c.execute("INSERT INTO sites VALUES('S900000', 'contact_name', '12345', 'contact_email', '12345', '12345')")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

#Site_ID entry box
text = Label(root, text="Please enter the Site ID.") 
text.grid(row=0, column=1)

x = Entry(root) 
x.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)
Label(root, text="Site ID").grid(row=1, sticky=W)

# button to Populate from existing contact
button3 = tk.Button(root, text='Select Contact.', command=CurSelet)
button3.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=tk.E)

#Contact detail entry
text = Label(root, text="Contact Name.") 
text.grid(row=1, column=7)
cne = Entry(root)
cne.grid(row=1, column=8, columnspan=2)

text = Label(root, text="Contact Number.") 
text.grid(row=2, column=7)
cnbre = Entry(root)
cnbre.grid(row=2, column=8, columnspan=2)

text = Label(root, text="Contact Email.") 
text.grid(row=3, column=7)
cee = Entry(root)
cee.grid(row=3, column=8, columnspan=2)

text = Label(root, text="Mobile Number.") 
text.grid(row=4, column=7)
cme = Entry(root)
cme.grid(row=4, column=8, columnspan=2)

text = Label(root, text="Alternate Number.") 
text.grid(row=5, column=7)
cae = Entry(root)
cae.grid(row=5, column=8, columnspan=2)

button5 = tk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=delete)
button5.grid(row=9, column=7, sticky=tk.E)

button6 = tk.Button(root, text='Add', command=add)
button6.grid(row=9, column=8, sticky=tk.E)

root.mainloop()
```

I simply cannot see what is locking the data into these test boxes.

Answer (score 1):

All your `pop_xxx` functions create new Entry widgets, and put them into local variables where the other functions cannot see them.

To write to a global variable, you would have to use the [global statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

```
def pop_name(...):
    global cne
    cne = Entry(root)
    ...
```

However, you do not actually need to recreate the widgets.
Just reuse the existing ones:

```
def pop_name(...):
    cne.delete(...)
    ...
```

Comment: Apologies for missing the Python tag, will ensure I get this next time.

Comment: This indeed was my issue, my heartfelt thanks for the solution, I'd been running in circles for days.